# What is better 2 tables 28 columns or 1 table 56 columns

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL to store historical data for my weather station so that I can come up with and report monthly and yearly records.

I have a table with 28 columns and 1 row which works well with the monthly data.

I wish now to process data to make comparisons with yearly data.  To do this requires a further 30+ columns with 1 row.

What do people think is the most efficient:

(a) Create a separate table for the yearly data or

(b) simply add the necessary number of columns for the yearly data to the one existing table.

Thanks

Keith Griffin
Brisbane, Australia

Comment: You haven't posted your schema but I suspect you already have it wrong. Set up a table with one row per set of readings and a date (and time if appropriate). Then you just add data. Monthly and yearly reports come from running queries over a date range.

Comment: One table, 3 columns

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to add necessary columns in single table only.

There is one major headache when you split columns in two table which is they all will have same primarykey but  you will have to maintain primarykey in two tables + more complex query may need to be write in update,insert and delete.

So as per Database Normalization rules you should keep all columns in one table.

Check out [database Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: So, it's -1 for paragraphs 1, 2 , & 3. + 1 for paragraph 4